# Using Smallest Width configuration qualifier

Tags: android, configuration, drawable, qualifiers

Is it valid to use drawable-swdp- like drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi?

Below is my scenario:
My Acer iconia tab A501 (10") has a resolution of 1280x800 and density mdpi(160dp).
It is expected to take the resource from drawable-sw720dp-mdpi.
But the resource is being taken from drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi.

I have following folders:
drawable-sw720dp
drawable-sw720dp-mdpi
drawable-sw720dp-hdpi
drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi

is this the way this qualifier is to be used?

or Is the density already considered while calculating the smallest width.So should i be having only one folder of the format:
drawable-sw720dp

Comment: As for me I used size-selection qualifiers for my resources and it worked pretty well. e.g. I used "drawable-large-xhdpi" and "drawable-xhdpi" (the same as "drawable-normal-xhdpi") to separate tablet and phone resources with xhdpi density.

Comment: What about using smallestWidth qualifiers?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. My only difference is that I'm adding -v14 to the end of each of my folders. Did you ever find an answer @ArunAntony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and tracked this down. I believe there was a bug in ICS (Android 4.0.3 for me) where non-XHDPI devices take XHDPI values. Because most XHDPI devices started off in Jelly Bean (Nexus 4, Nexus 10), qualifying the folders with -v16 at the end (instead of nothing or -v14) solves the problem. 10" non-XHDPI devices running Jelly Bean do not have this bug so it seems to work. This does mean any XHDPI devices pre-JB will be broken, but I'm okay taking that risk.

Answer (score 0):

Tablets of resolution like 1280x800  gets their resources from drawable-xhdpi of course if the device is of the density hdpi.

So designing for tablet to for different resolution you will have to create different folders of images with appropriate resolution name.

I think this will help you more .
 http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

thanks

Comment: Confused. 10" tablets of 1280x800 are mdpi density.