# Abstract out a drawable for different OS versions for a theme?

Tags: android

I'm targeting api 14 and above. In /values/styles.xml, I have this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/foo</item>
</style>
```

but for api 16 and above, I'd like to use a different drawable for windowBackground.

The "AppTheme" entry has a lot of attributes set in it right now, and I don't want to duplicate AppTheme in a v16 folder. Is there a way to abstract out just the windowBackground attribute, something like:

```
//  /values/styles.xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@myDefinition</item>
</style>

<drawable id="myDefinition">@drawable/foo1</drawable>

//  /values-v14/styles.xml
<drawable id="myDefinition">@drawable/foo2</drawable>
```

This way I can keep AppTheme defined in only one place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `drawable folder` for `v-16` or `v-14` so when the device is api 16/14 then it will grab that folder and use your `drawable` to your `Style` xml .

```
drawable-xhdpi-v16
```

Comment: Right but then don't I need a folder for all the densities? It would work but was hoping android provided a more elegant solution

Comment: @user3203425 nope there is none other solution rather than declaring a folder that accept a specified API level

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that using `drawable-v14/` would be a better solution.

See this other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494670/using-smallest-width-configuration-qualifier). It's not a duplicate of your question, but it seems to give the right answer.